# Carrusel en Bootstrap no se muestra correctamente

Tags: bootstrap-carousel

Estoy tratando de mostrar el siguiente carrusel en mi sitio web:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/JohnHalsey/abmtmjyz/

Pero en vez de aparecerme en varias columnas, sólo me aparece la primera columna pegada a la izquierda y nada más.

[image: Carrusel no carga bien]

He aquí el código de mi página donde está el slider:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/codelco/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el código que activa el carrusel y que hace que se repitan los diferentes items está en el archivo `js/carrusel.js` y es el siguiente:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

el problema es que estás ejecutando el código JavaScript en el `head` antes de que se hayan cargado los elementos que intenta manipular que están en el `body`. En el JSFiddle te funciona sin problemas porque has puesto el código en la parte de JS que se ejecuta OnLoad (cuando la página ya se ha cargado) y por eso los elementos ya existen y no tienes el problema.

Para solucionarlo, tienes dos opciones:

1. Encapsula el contenido de `carrusel.js` dentro de un `$(document).ready` para que se ejecute cuando la página haya terminado; o bien
2. Mueve la carga de los archivos JS al final del documento, justo antes del cierre del `body` (práctica recomendada porque así no interferirán en la carga de la página)

Si haces lo segundo, el código se verá así y como puedes ver funciona sin problemas (cambie la referencia a carrusel.js por su contenido directamente):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Codelco</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 <nav class="navbar ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar" style="color: black;"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar" style="color: black;"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar" style="color: black;"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/Codelco-Lab-Layout-1.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
     
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"> Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Convocatoria</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Objetivos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Bases</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Postulación</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

 </header>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
  <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div id="polina">
   <h1>LLEVA AL MERCADO TU IDEA <br>
   O PROYECTO BASADO EN COBRE, SUBPRODUCTOS Y LITIO</h1>
   
   <p>Conéctate con expertos en investigación, desarrollo, negocios y más.<br>
   Postula con tu proyecto no minero para dar solución y apertura a diferentes mercados.</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Ver Bases</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button" style="margin-left: 30px;">Postular Proyecto</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" style="text-align: center; padding: 60px;">
  <h1>Innovación y desarrollo</h1>
  <p>Creemos que el mundo puede funcionar mejor gracias<br>
  a las propiedades del cobre, sus subproductos (como el molibdeno) y otros minerales como el litio. </p>
 </div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <h3>Bootstrap 3 Multiple Slide Carousel</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="row" style="background-color: gold; text-align: center; padding: 50px;">
  <p>Codelco Lab te invita a potenciar y desarrollar proyectos vinculados a nuevos usos del cobre y molibdeno<br>
  Conectamos las innovaciones y desarrollos tecnológicos con el mercado, a través de la vinculación entre la ciencia, el emprendimiento y la empresa.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="row" style="background-color: gold; text-align: center; padding: 60px;">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="img/paris.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" width="80" height="80">
   <p style="margin-top: 5px;">Exploración</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="img/paris.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" width="80" height="80">
   <p style="margin-top: 5px;">Gestión de Proyectos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="img/paris.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" width="80" height="80">
   <p style="margin-top: 5px;">Crecimiento</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <img src="http://codelcolab.feriapixel.cl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/flux_os.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 90px;">
   <h1>Somos una aceleradora,<br>
   incubadora y consultora</h1>
   <p>Nuestro modelo de ingresos<br>
   es en base a acuerdos comerciales livianos<br>
   con royalties asociados<br>
   y opciones de compras en compañías</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 50px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span> Acelerar time to market</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 50px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span> Articulación con stakeholders relevantes</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 50px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span> Basado en acuerdos comerciales</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 50px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span> Activa relación con universidades y centros tecnológicos</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 50px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span> Desarrollo y crecimiento de compañías apalancándose con fondos de inversión</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 50px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span> Fuerte confinanciamiento con instrumentos públicos y privados</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" style="background-color: black; color: #fff; text-align: center; padding: 50px;" >
  <h1>CODELCO LAB</h1>
  <p>conecta innovación y desarrollos tecnológicos para llevaros al mercado.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="row" >
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: green; text-align: center; padding-top: 250px; padding-bottom: 60px;"><h2 style="color: #fff; border: 2px solid;">VER BASES</h2></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: orange; text-align: center; padding-top: 250px; padding-bottom: 60px;"><h2 style="color: #fff; border: 2px solid;">DESCARGAR BASES</h2></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; text-align: center; padding-top: 250px; padding-bottom: 60px;"><h2 style="color: #fff; border: 2px solid;">POSTULAR PROYECTO</h2></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" style="background-image: url('img/LOUSKYi.jpg'); padding-top: 80px; padding-bottom: 80px; color: #fff; position: relative;">
  <div style="position: relative; left: 700px;"><h1 >Contacto</h1>
  <p>Escríbenos a jmujica@endeavor.cl</p>
  &nbsp;
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">ENVIAR CORREO</a>
  </div>
  
  
 </div>
 </div>
  
  <script src="js/video.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="js/carrusel.js"></script>-->
  <script>
    
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
    </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, puse el script al final del body y asunto arreglado. Qué fácil era.